in which situation i have to use transformation instead of sql query in informatica powercenter?
If I can achieve it by writing SQL, is there no need to use the transformation component? and  I wanna know in what situation using transformation is better than sql query ? I heard coverting the transformation logic to sql query is more effcient ,is that right? Thank you for ur answering!

Yes, you are right. SQL running in database is usually faster than Informatica transformations.
Here are reasons of above statement -

Databases are optimized to process/transform large data efficiently - so they are the best to do any DB operations.
Some informatica transformations(agg, lkp, rank, srt) fetches data from source, store it in memory/space, then do transformations/lookup and load into target. All these steps takes time and CPU/IO. Naturally it takes more time for Infa transformations to process the data.
Reducing number of records, or number of columns in SQL DB is way efficient than using informatica to transform them all.

But in some cases you cant really use DB transformations/SQL -

When you have to join multiple tables from different databases, when you want to read from a file, do lookup from a flat file, do persistent lookup etc.
When you have some tricky transformations like SQL transformation to do some kind of loop, XML, cobol, normalizer etc.
When you have really complex, multiple table dependent logic which needs complex SQL and sometime impossible to achieve in SQL. In this case SQL becomes inefficient and non-maintainable to use.
Informatica is an ETL tool and can read from variety of sources (like file, cobol, xml, xls, table/view from many databases), transform and load into disparate types of targets. And it is meant for ETL purpose which make life easier when you are trying to implement & maintain a complex business logic. Large SQLs are usually difficult to maintain...

In summary, yes, in 80% cases your statement is true but there are always 20% exceptions and we need to do some analysis before deciding...

Running SQL is usually faster, indeed. But it requires resources. Consider heavy loaded Transaction System. It usually needs to process tons of transactions in miliseconds.
Now, if your run some complex calculations to get multiple KPIs (YtY, MtM, etc.) across number of categories (regions, products, etc.) - this is very resource consuming and will impact the system performance. If it will be possible at all.
Now Informatica (and any other ETL tool) will give you the possibility to read the data from source and take care of all the computation without affecting your source server. Just reading will happen, which is usually less of a problem for DB server.
That is on top of other cases where you need to combine multiple, different sources, not just single DB.
